# How to render an array of Object which is stored in local storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage, rendering, arrayobject

I am working on a chat project where I want to push some data of objects to the array. I am storing my data in the local storage and when I enter the values in the input field, local storage got updated and I can check the array in console where objects also added in the array but when I try to render the values from local storage to the browser, it couldn't update on the page. Your help will be appreciated. Here is my code

```
function storingDataInLocalStorage() {
    let storedData = localStorage.getItem("tweetsData")
    if (storedData) {
        let storedTweets = JSON.parse(storedData)
        if (storedTweets) {
            storedTweets === tweetsData
        }
    }
}
```

```
function render() {
    document.getElementById('feed').innerHTML = getFeedHtml()
}

function saveDataToLocalStorage() {
    localStorage.setItem("tweetsData", JSON.stringify(tweetsData));
}

render()
```

Here is my data

export let tweetsData = [
{
handle: `@TrollBot66756542` ,
profilePic: `images/troll.jpg`,
likes: 27,
retweets: 10,
tweetText: `Buy Bitcoin, ETH Make  low low prices.  Guaranteed return on investment. HMU DMs open!!`,
replies: [],
isLiked: false,
isRetweeted: false,
uuid: '4b161eee-c0f5-4545-9c4b-8562944223ee',
},
{
handle: `@Elon ✅`,
profilePic: `images/musk.png`,
likes: 6500,
retweets: 234,
tweetText: `I need volunteers for a one-way mission to Mars . No experience necessary`,
replies: [
{
handle: `@TomCruise ✅`,
profilePic: `images/tcruise.png`,
tweetText: `Yes! Sign me up!` ,
},
{
handle: `@ChuckNorris ✅`,
profilePic: `images/chucknorris.jpeg`,
tweetText: `I went last year`,
},
],
isLiked: false,
isRetweeted: false,
uuid: '3c23454ee-c0f5-9g9g-9c4b-77835tgs2',
},
{
handle: `@NoobCoder12`,
profilePic: `images/flower.png`,
likes: 10,
retweets: 3,
tweetText: `Are you a coder if you only know HTML?`,
replies: [
{
handle: `@StackOverflower ☣️`,
profilePic: `images/overflow.png`,
tweetText: `No. Onviosuly not. Go get a job in McDonald's.`,
},
{
handle: `@YummyCoder64`,
profilePic: `images/love.png`,
tweetText: `You are wonderful just as you are! ❤️`,
},
],
isLiked: false,
isRetweeted: false,
uuid: '8hy671sff-c0f5-4545-9c4b-1237gyys45',
},
]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlYQE.png)

When the user add some data into the textarea it should be rendered up onto the page and it still exist after the page refresh.

Comment: Although `storingDataInLocalStorage()` reads local storage and sometimes accesses the value of `tweetsData` (local modul or imported copy?), it has no side effects outside the function, and hence not particularly useful. Resources used by other items in the post lack detail.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you should have written the render update function, did you manually call the render update function after modifying the data?

Comment: Yes, I have manually write the function, and now the problem is resolved for me. Thank you for your suggestion.